# More XML Problems - Undeclared Entity 'nbsp'

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm getting the error:

> Line 49:             xml = r.ReadToEnd();
>   Line 50: 
>   Line 51:             System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xmlDoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xml);
>   Line 52:
>   Line 53:                var query = from p in xmlDoc.Descendants("member")

On my XML. When I run the code to generate the XML in an empty page, it runs without error, if I call the code within my webpage it throws this error. The only 'nbsp' on the page is a doctype declaration at the top of the XSLT:

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
```

I'm at a loss as to where this error is coming from and I am looking for suggestions please!

Thanks.

Here is the C# code that pulls in the XML:

```
protected void exportList(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String gid;
        gid = Request.QueryString["gid"].ToString();
        //XElement xml = XElement.Load("/members/listmembersxmlfeed?gid=" + gid);

        String xml = String.Empty;

        System.Net.WebResponse WR = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Request.Url + "/members/listmembersxmlfeed?gid=" + gid).GetResponse();

        System.IO.StreamReader r = new System.IO.StreamReader(WR.GetResponseStream());
        xml = r.ReadToEnd();

        System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xmlDoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var query = from p in xmlDoc.Descendants("member")
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = p.Element("name").Value,
                        Email = p.Element("email").Value
                    };

            foreach (var member in query)
            {
                    Response.Write("Employee: " + member.Name + " " + member.Email + "<br />");
            }
    }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: What is the actual error - you have shown the C# stack trace but the wording of the actual XML error should include the line number in the XML

Comment: Can you please provide full error text? May be, full xml too

Comment: You mean this line Mark? "System.Xml.XmlException: Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'. Line 113, position 18."

Comment: Yes - and then what is line 113 in the XML - I would not expect a DOCTYPE to be at that high a line

Comment: The C# probably does not matter here - the issue is the XML

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Changed the WebRequest.Create to a static URL instead of Request.Uri + "/listmembersxmlfeed?gid=" + gid, which solved it.

Comment: Amused as to why this is -2 as it is the answer? Or do I need to ask this in a moderator forum?

Answer (score 8):

**Your XML document must have a DTD declaring the @nbsp; entity**:

```
<!DOCTYPE topElementName [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
```

Otherwise the text is not a wellformed XML document (containes undefined entity), which the error message is telling you.

The fact that the XSLT stylesheet has this declaration is good only for the XSLT stylesheet. Such declaration is also needed separately for the XML document,